# Spring MVC Project arraylist load next onclick html field

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, arraylist, jstl

hi guys i have a Spring project with Data in database i have managed to retrieve the data as User Object in the ArrayList.

So when the user clicks on the button i need to move the Pointer one row of the ArrayList

ArrayList list = new ArrayList

for Example when the JSP is first time started the index 0 of the list is retrieved.

```
        Pointer-->User1
                  User2
                  User3
                  User4
                  User5
```

When The Client then clicks on the button the Pointer needs to go one row down

```
                  User1
       Pointer--> User2
                  User3
                  User4
                  User5
```

Is there a way just to use next like in Cursor in Arraylist or how is this to be Accomplished Thanks for some usefull information ideas.

Remember it's all in the JSP Page 
Don't know i worked with cursors but never in JSP so help would be Appreciated

I need to change the value of a html field by clicking on a button is this the way as described above or is there another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a specific element of an ArrayList with JSTL via `${userList[0]}`

Or you can use varStatus:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}" varStatus="counter">  
    <c:if test="${counter.count eq 1}">  
         ${user}  
    </c:if>  
</c:forEach>
```

You may be better off with a javacript array of [JSON](http://www.json.org/) objects. See: [google-gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)